# Getting Posts from page using Graph Api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get Post data from a page using /{post-id} as per the documentation given in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post

But what I get is only `{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"created_time":"xxxx","story":"xxxxx","id":"1653069348287211_1842135602713917"}, error: null}`

I am not getting any data as per the doc like `properties`, `shares`, `permalink_url` so on.

Do I need to have a specific access token rather than a valid access token got from logging in? For ex: I need a page access token to get detailed data on posts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need a token to access the page to view posts from a public page. Could you be more specific with the code you are using? I can help you.